# save() and object.create note worked in django

Tags: django

I'm new, trying to save and fail
gives an error message, whsts do?
p.save() and p=Post.objects.create not worked [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApPlq.jpg)

Comment: You should probably `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: Yes , many times )))))

Comment: whether it says ..the migrations are applied or no changes detected.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
 body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
 date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return '{}' .format(self.title)

the rest is all in the console:

>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> p = Post(title = 'titlef', slug = 'slug', body = 'body')
>>> p
<Post: title>
>>> p.body
'fsdfsdf'

and today save() not wroked again